# change to a different url. Simple to change one by one different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

you just want to change my url address.

if I have "save.com/newdocumente.html"

I want the new form is so "save.com/#jhjghgggg"

and it works.

I want a button that says generate link.

as does the "mega.co.nz" site

not know where to start

Comment: Do you have any code that you could show us?

Comment: I do not know how you can start with JS

Comment: You have bunch of free tutorials online. May be to start there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the button

```
<button id="the-button">"Generate Link" </button>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('the-button').onclick=function(e){
    document.location.hash = '#newStash';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have bind an event listener to your button which listens for click events on it and change the URL as a result:

**the button**

```
<input type="button" id="the-button" value="Generate Link" />
<!-- or whatever your button is -->
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#the-button').on('click', function(e) {
  location.href = 'http://the.new.location.here';
});
```